# Springboot not finding graphql controller resulting in a 404 for /graphql

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql-java

I'm trying to make a sample springboot graphql app work.   The graphIql explorer loads (note the 'i') at `localhost:8080/graphiql`, but it looks like the `/graphql` endpoint is returning 404.  Below is the app

error

```json
{
  "timestamp": "2022-09-29T18:22:29.706+00:00",
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "path": "/graphql"
}
```

```java
@Controller
public class SampleController {

    private final DataRepository repository;

    public SampleController(DataRepository dataRepository) {
        this.repository = dataRepository;
    }

    @QueryMapping
    public String greeting() {
        return this.repository.getBasic();
    }

    @QueryMapping
    public Mono<String> greetingMono() {
        return this.repository.getGreeting();
    }

    @QueryMapping
    public Flux<String> greetingsFlux() {
        return this.repository.getGreetings();
    }

    @SubscriptionMapping
    public Flux<String> greetings() {
        return this.repository.getGreetingsStream();
    }

}
```

The app

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

app properties

```
spring.graphql.graphiql.enabled=true
spring.graphql.graphiql.path=/graphiql
spring.graphql.schema.printer.enabled=true
spring.graphql.path=/graphql
```

pom dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

the schema

```
type Query {
    greeting: String
    greetingMono : String
    greetingsFlux : [String]
}
type Subscription {
    greetings: String
}
```

Update - I added a webflux controller and it finds that ok.  The `@QueryMapping` controller just isn't working

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    public TestController() {
    }

    @GetMapping("/test2")
    Mono<String> test() {
        return Mono.just("hi");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your dependencies seem conflicting/outdated, please have a look at [current reference doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html/) ..and e.g. [webflux-sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/tree/main/samples/webflux-websocket)

Comment: @xerx593 - I tried using the sample classes you linked plus updated my pom, and it doesn't work either

Comment: Unfortunately the samples are Gradle only ... Try https://www.google.com/search?q=gradle+2+maven ..but I suspect the `com.graphql-java*` dependencies (they are not part of sample)

Comment: Have you got any workaround for this? I'm also facing the same issue.